# Struct comparison in a priority queue

Tags: c++, struct

I want to get the most priority "packet" in my application. A packet is a basic structure containing only two fields: a std::string called name and an integer as a priority. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

typedef struct packet {
    int priority;
    std::string name;

    friend bool operator<(const packet& a, const packet& b) {
        return a.priority > b.priority;
    }

}
packet;

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<packet*> packets; //I must use packet* as pointer (restriction).

    packet* p1 = new packet();
    packet* p2 = new packet();
    packet* p3 = new packet();

    p1->priority = 200;
    p2->priority = 20;
    p3->priority = 89;

    p1->name= "test";
    p2->name = "test2";
    p3->name = "test3";

    packets.push(p1);
    packets.push(p2);
    packets.push(p3);

    std::cout << "first: " << packets.top()->name;
    packets.pop();
    std::cout << "second: " << packets.top()->name;
    packets.pop();
    std::cout << "third: " << packets.top()->name;
    packets.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

The output:
*first: test3 second: test2 third: test1*

But i want to get the most priorities packets first. How can I do to solve this problems? Thanks!

Comment: You need a `comparator` for your priority queue

Comment: [Priority queue of struct's pointers](//stackoverflow.com/a/13269561)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

typedef struct packet {
    int priority;
    std::string name;

    friend bool operator<(const packet& a, const packet& b) {
        return a.priority > b.priority;
    }

}
packet;

struct comparator
{
    bool operator()(const packet * a, const packet *b)
    {
        return a->priority > b->priority;
    }
};

//comparator f; edit - no need for this forgot to comment oops

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<packet*,vector<packet*>,comparator> packets; // i add comparator and vector<packet*> here

    packet* p1 = new packet();
    packet* p2 = new packet();
    packet* p3 = new packet();

    p1->priority = 200;
    p2->priority = 20;
    p3->priority = 89;

    p1->name= "test";
    p2->name = "test2";
    p3->name = "test3";

    packets.push(p1);
    packets.push(p2);
    packets.push(p3);

    std::cout << "first: " << packets.top()->name;
    packets.pop();
    std::cout << "second: " << packets.top()->name;
    packets.pop();
    std::cout << "third: " << packets.top()->name;
    packets.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

In your `std::priority_queue` you need to provide a `comparator` that compares the elements and prioritizes them.

I do this using a `struct` `comparator` with a `bool operator()(packet * a, packet *b)` what this does is that it lets you call the comparator objects `()` with 2 `packet*`s and then returns `true/false` (if the priority of first is > or < that of the second)

I also add `vector<packet*>` container type to the `std::priority_queue` to make that the default container (on which the heap is built). More info here :
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: Your `comparator` is unnecessarily duplicating code, and gets it wrong (since the order will be the reverse of the comparison in the `packet` struct).  Also, both parameters should be `const packet *`.  `bool operator()(const packet *a, const packet *b) { return *a < *b; }`

Comment: i agree with the `const` and ordering part - I think for an explanation it is good to make code verbose. I don't think my code is super concise - that was never the intention.

Comment: Some comments
1. Since c++, `typedef` is not required.
2. Unnecessary global `comparator f` is not required.
3. OP wants to sort by descending order. `a->priority > b->priority`

Comment: yes, `typedef` was copied over from OPs code, will get rid of the `global` object. Thank you

Comment: But you still have the duplicated code.  If you need to change the comparison, you need to do it in two places which is just asking for trouble.  Using `*a < *b` will reuse the existing code.

Comment: I agree with your point. As i mentioned in my answer, I was trying to introduce the concept of a `priority_queue` `comparator` argument hence the duplication. I explained it the way I thought would be most helpful to OP - and that is always up for debate. Nevertheless, I appreciate your comments.